# How to search Webelement inside webElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table WebElement 'A' and there is an other img(htlm tag) WebElement 'Child' inside the table.
And the child WebElement each time comes inside different Table column cell td(html tag).

I have a table cell WebElement 'TC'.

Now I need to verify that 'child' is present inside 'TC'.

Comment: can you provide html code and what you tried so far?

Comment: why not use a parsing engine like beautiful soup to filter the cells in the table?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Provide your work so I will try to help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
WebElement eleParent=driver.findElement(Locator);
WebElement eleChild=eleParent.findElement(Locator);
```